# Is a set in between two sets of equal measure measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Lebesgue sigma algebra is complete with respect to Lebesgue measure, which means that if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set with Lebesgue measure $0$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$, then $B$ is Lebesgue measurable as well.  But I'd like to know if something stronger is true.

Suppose that $A$ is a subset of $B$ which is a subset of $C$, where $A$ and $C$ are Lebesgue measurable sets and the Lebesgue measure of $A$ is equal to the Lebesgue measure of $C$.  Then my question is, does $B$ have to be Lebesgue measurable as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $A$ and $C$ are each Lebesgue measurable, then so is $C\setminus A$ and so by finite additivity it has measure zero.

But then $B\setminus A$ also has measure zero and hence is measurable, so $$B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$$ is the union of two measurable sets, hence is measurable.

Comment: Thanks, that was more trivial than I thought.  What about this: suppose that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist Lebesgue measurable sets $A$ and $C$ such that $A$ is a subset of $B$ which is a subset of $C$ and the Lebesgue measure of $C$ minus the Lebesgue measure of $A$ is less than $\epsilon$.  Then does $B$ have to be Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Oh, I think that's also a trivial yes.  You just take the union of the $A$'s and the intersection of the $C$'s.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yup, that's correct.

Comment: @Noah Don't the sets $A$ and $C$ need to be of finite measure to conclude that $\mu(C\backslash A)=0$? Take $C=\mathbb{R}$ and  $A=(0,\infty)$.